# React Typescript type a void function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Why don't get an error after typing a function that should return nothing and then access `props.onClick` inside `Message` component that returns something value?

```
type MessageProps = {
  onClick: () => void,
  value?: string
}

const Message: React.FunctionComponent<MessageProps> = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Example message</h1>
      <button onClick={props.onClick}>click</button>
    </>
  )
}

const App = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Message onClick={() => 2} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Returning void is not the same as doing nothing. `onClick` expects a function, and you're giving it one

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38758#issuecomment-633230559

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fundamentally what you're asking is why this assignment doesn't result in an error:

```typescript
type VF = () => void;

const f: VF = () => 2;
```

([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAagYlAvFAFASiQPigNwPYCWAJgNwBQZAxngHYDOwUAZgFywLLpZQBMJQA))

It's because a function type with a `void` return type doesn't require that the function assigned doesn't return anything. From [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#return-type-void):

> **Return type `void`**
>
> The `void` return type for functions can produce some unusual, but expected behavior.
>
> Contextual typing with a return type of `void` does **not** force functions to **not** return something. Another way to say this is a contextual function type with a `void` return type (`type vf = () => void`), when implemented, can return any other value, but it will be ignored.

*(their emphasis)*

If you think about it, that makes sense, since all JavaScript functions return something — if there's no explicit `return`, or there's a `return;` with no value, the return value is `undefined`.

```js
function a() { }
function b() { return; }
console.log("a", a());
console.log("b", b());
```

(I think that's covered [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes.html#sec-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation) [for `a`] and [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations.html#sec-return-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation) [for `b`] in the JavaScript spec, just for what it's worth.)